# Solving linear Diophantine equation

Tags: python, diophantine

I am trying to code an algorithm in Python in order to solve linear Diophantine equations.

I think my algorithm is correct because I have tested it on a paper, however when I run it, it returns strange values.

My code:

```
def solve_Dioph(a,b,c):
    m1=1
    m2=0
    n1=0
    n2=1
    r1=a
    r2=b
    while r1%r2!=0:
        q=r1/r2
        aux=r1%r2
        r1=r2
        r2=aux
        aux3=n1-(n2*q)
        aux2=m1-(m2*q)
        m1=m2
        n1=n2
        m2=aux2
        n2=aux3
    return m2*c,n2*c;
```

It uses 7 variables and 3 auxiliar variables. After testing it with a pen and a paper, with this values:

```
a=65 b=14 c=4
```

I get

```
m2=-3*4 and n2=14*4
```

However, when I run it:

```
solve_Dioph(65,14,4)
```

It returns:

```
(-227/9, 16393/126)
```

Comment: This is genius, i must admit i never expected there would be an extended euclidean algorithm that doesn't use recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using Python 3 (as opposed to Python 2).  In Python 3, dividing two integers with `/` produces a float result.  However, you can force the Python 2 behavior by using the `//` operator.  Try changing the following line:

```
q=r1/r2
```

To:

```
q=r1//r2
```

Comment: You mean, "In Python 3, symbol `/` is floating-point division, and symbol `//` is integer division." The sentence "integer division returns a float result" is a self-contradiction.

Comment: @Stef It was poorly worded.  I used "integer division" when I really meant "dividing two integers with `/`".  I've updated the wording.